# Corba IDL: default value for struct members

Tags: c++, corba, idl

Is it possible to define a default value for struct members in CORBA IDL?
Let's take the following struct as an example:

```
struct Example
{
    boolean test;
};
```

If I compile this IDL to C++, the variable 'test' will be uninitialized after object creation. I would like it to be always set to false until it is explicitly switched to true.

Comment: You might want to indicate _how_ you compile IDL to C++. Current C++ allows initializers for members, i.e. `bool test = false;` but I don't know if your IDL compiler understands that.

Comment: @MSalters I was thinking of a constructor initialization list. Unfortunately, I cannot use C++ 11. For compilation I use omniidl from omniORB 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OMG IDL to C++ mapping doesn't default initialize struct members. As you mentioned the IDL to C++11 mapping does specify a default value for all types, including all basic types. At the moment you have a compiler/OS supporting C++11 you should be able to use the IDL to C++11 mapping, it doesn't require you to use C++11 in your application code.

Answer (score 2):

I have used omniORB and VisiBroker for CORBA implementation. None of these idl compiler support default value structure.